# Index of /mobile/mobile app code/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r/android/arch/lifecycle/livedata/core

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

My project is in React-Native and i was just trying to run it on a device and got that error, so I tried to clean the project from Android Studio and ./Gradlew clean from Android folder and then i restarted the server but still it was not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to run adb reverse tcp `8081` tcp `8081` for it to work but I am going to leave the question opened just in case someone else experience that issue.